# How to cancate column value while updating records

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Mysql Table like below :

```
Id  Name  Points  Done_by

1    x     20      0

2    y     30      0

3    z     10      0
```

In my code i have 3 actions , ( Apporve , Reject , Close ) . If the Supervisor role based persons can approve , reject , close the records inside the table .

So if any supervisor  is  approve  /  Reject  / close any record means their id is maintained into the Done_by  column .

What i want is if one supervisor  Approve the Id 1 means , then the table records will be like below ,

```
Id   Name   Points  Done_by  
1     x      20      emp10
```

If another supervisor is rejected means the table records will be look like below,

```
Id   Name   Points  Done_by  
1     x      20      emp10 ,  emp 5
```

Same for Closing .

How to do this in PHP Mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this SQL Query : `UPDATE your_table SET Done_by = (CASE Done_by WHEN 0 THEN 'your_supervisor_id' ELSE CONCAT(Done_by, ', ', 'your_supervisor_id) END);`

Check [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) the manual function for CONCAT

Comment: sorry it is not working for me,  here is my query  " UPDATE summary SET done_by = (CASE done_by WHEN 0 THEN '".$done_by_id."' ELSE CONCAT(done_by, ', ', '".$done_by_id."') END) where id ='".$id."' "

Comment: Can you do an echo of the SQL generated by PHP ?

Comment: if i echo means UPDATE hr_performance_summary SET done_by = (CASE done_by WHEN 0 THEN 'A-1' ELSE CONCAT(done_by, ', ', 'A-1') END) where id ='1'

Comment: This query should work if of course you have a row with the Id 1.
Have you the autocommit set to false ?

Comment: But i am using the laravel raw format but it is not working